# Create N-Gram using Regular Expression in PySpark

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe column with names:

```
|   name     |
--------------
|Lebron James|
|Kyrie Irving|
|Kevin Durant|
```

I want to create a new column such as the following:

```
|   name     |         trigram          |
-----------------------------------------
|Lebron James| Leb ebr bro on  Jam ame es
|Kyrie Irving| ...
|Kevin Durant| ...
```

So far I have

```
df.withColumn("trigram", regex_replace(col("name"), "([A-Za-z0-9\s]{3})(?!$)", r"$1 "))
```

But this outputs:

```
|   name     |         trigram       |
--------------------------------------
|Lebron James| Leb ron Ja  mes
|Kyrie Irving| Kyr ie  Irv ing
|Kevin Durant| Kev in  Dur ant
```

Note: It is important to NOT use udfs. I could simply do what I want with a udf and list comprehension, but I'm looking to do this in the most optimal way since the actual data has hundreds of millions of rows

Comment: Maybe `regex_replace(col("name"), "(?=(.{3})).", r"$1 ")` will do?

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks! Im still a novice to regular expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```py
regex_replace(col("name"), "(?=(.{3})).", r"$1 ")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vOUz85/1). Details:

- `(?=(.{3}))` - a positive lookahead that captures (into Group 1, `$1`) the three chars other than line break chars immediately to the right of the current location
- `.` - any char but a line break char, consumed (it will be removed, and replaced by the 3 char streak starting from this char).